# launch an app from my activity and get a time user uses another app

Tags: android, android-studio

i want when user click on button open another application and i want to get the time of uses those application which user launch with my application

i want to get the time of user used the application

example :
Application (A) is my application and application (B) is another application

from (A) when user click a button open (B) application and then when (B) application closed then get the uses time in (A) application

is this possible then please help me

Answer (score 0):

Not in general.  You can use an assumption the the next time your activity is RESUMED that the user went right back to your app and just compare timestamps.  But that assumes the user didn't hit the home button and go elsewhere.  Or hit screen off and do something else for an hour.  There's no way to get an accurate time for how long he spent interacting with another app, just how long it took him to come back to yours.  You also then have to deal with corner cases around your activity being killed in the background for resources.